# C# https login and download file

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have successful connected to the login page, however, i'm not sure how to login and grab the file thats behind the login.  Below is the code i'm using to make the connect.

```
  private static bool bypassAllCertificateStuff(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public static void Processing()
    {
        string url = "https://app/templat";
        HttpWebRequest request;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        CookieContainer cookies;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
            = ((sender, cert, chain, errors) => cert.Subject.Contains("YourServerName"));
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(bypassAllCertificateStuff);
        try
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                cookies = request.CookieContainer;



                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                String postData = "j_login=user&j_password=user&submit=Send";
                byte[] data = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                //Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                request.CookieContainer = cookies;

                //stream.Close();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string tmp = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();


                //response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                //WebClient wbClient = new WebClient();
                //wbClient.DownloadFile("https://app/template/simple%2Screen.vm", @"C:\test.xls");

                response.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client was unable to connect!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

I'm positive the download doesn't work and i'm sure `String postData` doesn't perform what intend it to.

Below is the code for the website login

```
<pre>
<form name=\"loginform\" method=\"post\" action=\"j_security_check\" onSubmit=\"javascript:fixFields();\">
<br>
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"80%\">
<tr>
<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\" nowrap=\"nowrap\">
<div id=\"bannerDiv\" class=\"groupingBorder\" style=\"visibility:hidden;position:relative;background-color:#FFFFFF; overflow:auto;\">
</div>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class=\"contentrtanbld\" nowrap width=\"50%\">Name:</td>
 <td class=\"contentltan\" nowrap width=\"50%\">
<input type=\"text\" name=\"j_username\" id=\"j_username\" value=\"\" class=\"authGroupWidth\" size=\"20\"></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td class=\"contentrtanbld\" nowrap>Password:</td>
<td class=\"contentltan\" nowrap>
<input type=\"password\" name=\"j_password\" id=\"j_password\" value=\"\" class=\"authGroupWidth\" size=\"20\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</pre>
```

And the file I want to download is via this link
`https://app/template/simple%2Screen.vm`

I'm able to make the connection to the webpage but i'm unsure how to login and download the file.

Please see update to code.  This is still not logging in and i'm not sure why.

```
 string url = "https://mgr/app";
        HttpWebRequest request;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
            = ((sender, cert, chain, errors) => cert.Subject.Contains("YourServerName"));
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(bypassAllCertificateStuff);
        try
        {
            string cookieHeader;
            string formParams = string.Format("j_login={0}&j_password={1}", "user", "user");
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream os = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
            cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

            string pageSource;
            string BehinPath = "https://mgr/app/action/store.VivolAction/eventsubmit_dopreparevivollist/ignored";
            WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(BehinPath);
            getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
            WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

This is the new code, there is 1 cookie, however when i try the first post it never logs in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has the following problems that I can see:

1. Doesn't properly handle the cookie container. CookieContainer should be initialized and then passed to your HttpWebRequest, not the other way around.
2. Does not cleanup disposable objects. Failing to dispose an object can result in the object hanging around for quite a while before the garbage collector catches up with it.
3. Does not account for the form action. Your form action will cause a submit to a different location.
4. Unnecessarily performs the first operation as a POST. Use GET instead.
5. Does not set the referer when performing the POST operation.

Try the following code:

```
    Uri url = new Uri("http://app/templat");
    HttpWebRequest request = null;

    // Uncomment the line below only if you need to accept an invalid certificate, i.e. a self-signed cert for testing.
    // ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    request.Method = "GET";
    HttpStatusCode responseStatus;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        responseStatus = response.StatusCode;
        url = request.Address;
    }

    if (responseStatus == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        UriBuilder urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
        urlBuilder.Path = urlBuilder.Path.Remove(urlBuilder.Path.LastIndexOf('/')) + "/j_security_check";

        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlBuilder.ToString());
        request.Referer = url.ToString();
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            string postData = "j_username=user&j_password=user&submit=Send";
            requestWriter.Write(postData);
        }

        string responseContent = null;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseContent = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client was unable to connect!");
    }
```

Comment: huh, so if I wanted to go to the url underneath of that of /mgr/app/action/storeVivolAction/eventsubmit_dopreparevivollist/ignored how would i continue that?  Do I have to produce more cookies?

Comment: Just do another request for the next url you want to visit and keep using the same cookie container `request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;`. If you're not submitting data to the server make sure that your request method is GET. You should continue using the same cookie container for whatever additional web requests constitute a single session.

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing, you need to initiate the cookie container before the first request:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
```

then you need to pass it on each request(now you're just instantiating it again, thus losing all the cookies):

```
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

the response you're getting will fill the cookie container with the necessary cookies.

Furthermore, as I see you are already doing, you need to perform a series of Request/Response on the website and track the cookies. Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what exactly how you need to formulate your POST strings to correctly login to the website.

Comment: I thought that is what i'm doing here cookies = request.CookieContainer;

Comment: @Mike - can you debug and see if it actually fills in the cookies, it looks to me that by doing this you might be overwriting them.

Comment: @Mike - if all that looks good, then in the second request, read the response and the cookies(this would mean that you are logged in) and then perform another one to download the file.

Comment: I think thats the issue, it never attempts to log in, when i read the SR.toend it is the login page.

Comment: I have and it continues to remain at the login back, i'm not sure how I am posting the credentials at all

Comment: when you can, can you take a look at the update, i've made sure the cookie is there

Comment: @Mike - try Fiddler, it will give you an insight of the GETs/POSTs...and then try to reproduce the steps in your code using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse