# How to use InternetQueryOption in C# interop?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling, wininet

In my C# code I want to use InternetQueryOption which is defined in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) such as:

```
BOOL InternetQueryOption(
  __in     HINTERNET hInternet,
  __in     DWORD dwOption,
  __out    LPVOID lpBuffer,
  __inout  LPDWORD lpdwBufferLength
);
```

In my C# code I wrote:

```
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern bool InternetQueryOption(
            IntPtr hInternet, 
            uint dwOption, 
            IntPtr lpBuffer, 
            ref int lpdwBufferLength);
```

My C++ code:

```
...
HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST","/BM-Login/auth-cup", NULL, NULL, accept, secureFlags, 0);
    DWORD dwFlags;
    DWORD dwBuffLen = sizeof(dwFlags);

    InternetQueryOption (hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
            (LPVOID)&dwFlags, &dwBuffLen);

    dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA;
      dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_REVOCATION;
      dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;
      dwFlags |= SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_WRONG_USAGE;

    InternetSetOption (hRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
                            &dwFlags, sizeof (dwFlags) );
...
```

**How to write the same in C#?** Thanks. (Sorry for my very bad English)

Comment: Is using WebRequest, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx, not an option for some reason?

Comment: Jamie See repost your comment as answer and I get It

Comment: Posted as answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using manged code for this instead of doing this via interop. Have a look at the [WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx). Also, have a look at my answer to the stackoverflow question [C# https login and download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841344/c-sharp-https-login-and-download-file/9842925#9842925) for a working example of how this class can be used.