# C# WebClient OpenRead

Tags: c#, webclient

Could someone help with parsing website.
I have parsed lots of sites but this one is interesting, the inner code is generated dynamically with php file. So I tried to use WebClient like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string postData = "getProducts=1&category=340&brand=0";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

client.Headers.Add("POST", "/ajax.php HTTP/1.1");
client.Headers.Add("Host", site);
client.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
client.Headers.Add("Origin", "http://massup.ru");
client.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11");
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.Headers.Add("Content-length", byteArray.Length.ToString());
client.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://massup.ru/category/proteini");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "cart=933a71dfee2baf8573dfc2094a937f0d; r_v=YToyOntpOjA7YTo3OntzOjU6Im1vZGVsIjtzOjI2OiIxMDAlIFdoZXkgUHJvdGVpbiA5MDgg0LPRgCI7czozOiJ1cmwiO3M6MzQ6Im11bHRpcG93ZXItMTAwLXdoZXktcHJvdGVpbi05MDgtZ3IiO3M6NToiYnJhbmQiO3M6MTA6Ik11bHRpcG93ZXIiO3M6ODoiY2F0ZWdvcnkiO3M6Mzk6ItCh0YvQstC%2B0YDQvtGC0L7Rh9C90YvQtSDQuNC30L7Qu9GP0YLRiyI7czo5OiJzY2F0ZWdvcnkiO3M6Mzc6ItCh0YvQstC%2B0YDQvtGC0L7Rh9C90YvQuSDQuNC30L7Qu9GP0YIiO3M6NToicHJpY2UiO3M6MToiMCI7czo0OiJpY29uIjtzOjM3OiJodHRwOi8vbWFzc3VwLnJ1L2ltYWdlcy9pY29uXzQ3NTIuanBnIjt9aToxO2E6Nzp7czo1OiJtb2RlbCI7czoxNzoiTWF0cml4IDIuMCA5ODQg0LMiO3M6MzoidXJsIjtzOjE2OiJtYXRyaXgtMi0wLTk4NC1nIjtzOjU6ImJyYW5kIjtzOjc6IlN5bnRyYXgiO3M6ODoiY2F0ZWdvcnkiO3M6Mzk6ItCh0YvQstC%2B0YDQvtGC0L7Rh9C90YvQtSDQuNC30L7Qu9GP0YLRiyI7czo5OiJzY2F0ZWdvcnkiO3M6Mzc6ItCh0YvQstC%2B0YDQvtGC0L7Rh9C90YvQuSDQuNC30L7Qu9GP0YIiO3M6NToicHJpY2UiO3M6NDoiMTE5MCI7czo0OiJpY29uIjtzOjM3OiJodHRwOi8vbWFzc3VwLnJ1L2ltYWdlcy9pY29uXzEwMDguanBnIjt9fQ%3D%3D; PHPSESSID=933a71dfee2baf8573dfc2094a937f0d");

Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://massup.ru/ajax.php");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(s);
data.Close();
reader.Close();
```

But it gives me an error!

Could someone help me with this kind of parsing.

Comment: "Gives me an error" is rather unhelpful.  What error do you get?

Comment: It doesn't matter you capture the output of a PHP script, because you're reading the output itself.

Comment: You aren't actually parsing anything here, just fetching.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [C# https login and download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841344/c-sharp-https-login-and-download-file), which has working code that correctly handles HTTP POSTs, then clean up what you have based on it. After you've done that, if you still need help, post your updated code and a clearer description of what specific errors or exceptions you are seeing.